# comparing two graphs by The degree of vertices

Tags: c++, graph

i write a code for showing two graphs which the same degree of vertices are equal. but i don't know why it doesn't work correctly and give incorrect answer.for example :for two graphs like:

```
[0 1 1 0 0     [0 1 0 1 0 
 1 0 1 0 0      1 0 1 0 0
 1 0 0 1 0      0 1 0 1 0 
 0 0 1 0 1      0 0 1 0 1
 0 0 0 1 0]     0 0 0 1 0]
```

but it should not write the message that "two graphs don't have the same degree of vertices" but it write it.and i don't know what should i do.
if it's possible please guide me.

```
int temp = 0;
    int temp2 = 0;
    int gg = 1;
    for (int ia = 0; ia < m; ia++)
    {
        for (int ja = 0; ja < m; ja++)
        {
            if (j.f[ia][ja] == 1)
            {

                temp++;
            }

        }
        for (int i = 0; i < m; i++&&gg == 1)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < m; j++&&gg == 1)
            {
                if (g.f[i][j] == 1)
                {

                    temp2++;
                }
            }
            if (temp == temp2)
                gg = 0;
            else
            {
                cout << "two graphs don't have the same degree of vertices";
                system("pause");
                exit(1);

            }


        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
int temp=0;
int temp2=0;

for(int i = 0; i < m; i++)
  for(int j = 0; j < m; j++)
    temp += j.f[i][j];

for(int i = 0; i < m; i++)
  for(int j = 0; j < m; j++)
    temp2 += g.f[i][j];

if(temp!=temp2){
  cout<<"two graphics don't have the same degree of vertices";
  system("pause");
  exit(1);
}
```

What this code does is first finish checking the degree of vertices on both, and THEN compares. What your code is doing is nesting the check of the second entire  graph within the check of the first graph, and weird behavior is happening because the code is poorly structured. Finish checking both, then compare.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do here? I'm not totally understanding what you mean by "degree of vertices". Are you checking each row to see if they have the same number of 1's in them?

Comment: yes. my mean was that.the first code that you sent didn't work correctly but this one worked well.thank you

Comment: Since this has solved your problem, would you kindly mark it as the correct answer? Thanks!